# jekyll on github page has incorrect src (eg. "http://localhost:4000/assets/js/scripts.min.js")

Tags: github, jekyll

My project: https://github.com/sebastian3495/sebastian3495.github.io 
My website (current displayed without css rendered): https://sebastian3495.github.io/

**How can I have all links point to my github project instead of localhost?**

What am I missing? I am new to jekyll and web development isn't my strongest point, so please bear with me.

**EDIT: My config file hasbeen updated**

_config.yml

```
title:            Blog Title
description:      Describe your website here.

# put your disqus here
remote_theme: aron-bordin/neo-hpstr-jekyll-theme
disqus_shortname:
reading_time:     true # if true, shows the estimated reading time for a post
words_per_minute: 200
logo:             images/logo.png # logo visible in the topbar
excerpt_separator: <!--more-->
url: https://sebastian3495.github.io




# draw your top menu here
# each item must have a title and a url.
#   To list post categories. use type: 'categories'
#   To create sub categories. add a submenu item
# See the example
menu:
  - title: 'Home'
    url: '/'
  - title: 'Fork'
    url: 'http://github.com/aron-bordin/neo-hpstr-jekyll-theme'
  - title: 'Install'
    url: 'http://github.com/aron-bordin/neo-hpstr-jekyll-theme#installation'
  - title: 'Tags'
    url: '/tags'
  - title: 'Categories'
    url: '/categories'
    type: 'categories'
  - title: 'Favorites'
    url: '#'
    submenu:
      - title: 'Code Highlighter'
        url: '/intro/code-highlighting-post/'
      - title: 'Sample Post'
        url: '/intro/sample-post/'

# Owner/author information
owner:
  name:           Sebastian Nielsen
  site:           http://aronbordin.com
  avatar:         images/avatar.jpg
  bio:            "TEsting stuff off! . :D . It shouldn't be super long but a good two sentences or two should suffice."
  email:          you@email.com
  # Twitter nick for use in Twitter cards and follow button.
  twitter: aron_bordin # if no twitter in this config, the twitter follow button will be removed
  # GitHub nick for use in follow button in author block.
  github: aron-bordin

# Twitter account associated with the site if different from owner/author twitter account.
# Used in Twitter cards.
twitter:

# Social networking links used in author block underneath posts. Update and remove as you like.
social:
  - title: "github"
    url: "https://github.com/aron-bordin"
  - title: "linkedin"
    url: "https://br.linkedin.com/in/aronbordin"
  - title: "youtube"
    url: "https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCfnSek-9HPWOx5e2pH7VFgg"

# Background image to be tiled on all pages
background:

# Analytics and webmaster tools stuff goes here
google_analytics:
google_verify:
# https://ssl.bing.com/webmaster/configure/verify/ownership Option 2 content= goes here
bing_verify:

# http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones
timezone:    America/New_York
locale:      en_US
future:      true
highlighter: rouge
markdown:    kramdown
sass:
  sass_dir: _sass
  style: compressed

# https://github.com/mojombo/jekyll/wiki/Permalinks
permalink:   /:categories/:title/

# Amount of post to show on home page
paginate: 5

# if true, shows the floatting share buttons
float_share: true

# Octopress
# Default extensions
post_ext: md
page_ext: md
# Found in _templates/
post_layout: post
page_layout: page
# Format titles with titlecase?
titlecase: true

include: [".htaccess", "C:/Users/sebas/Documents/GitHub/Sebastian_Nielsen_Blog/_includes"]
exclude: ["demo/*", "lib", "config.rb", "Capfile", "config", "Gemfile", "Gemfile.lock", "README.md", "LICENSE", "log", "Rakefile", "Rakefile.rb", "tmp", "less", "*.sublime-project", "*.sublime-workspace", "test", "spec", "Gruntfile.js", "package.json", "node_modules"]
plugins: ["jekyll-paginate", "jekyll-remote-theme"]
theme: neo-hpstr-jekyll-theme
```

Comment: It's difficult to help without seeing your original code. Can you push it in a "source" branch ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you're using a third-party theme, I understand you followed the instructions to run `jekyll build` locally first and then uploaded the contents of your `./_site` directory.

The issue here is that recent versions of Jekyll automatically sets the `url` key to `http://localhost:4000` when you *build* locally.

You have two basic choices:

1. To use both third-party themes and third-party plugins on GitHub Pages, you need to build the site locally by changing the `JEKYLL_ENV` env to `production` (or anything else *other than `development`*)

   ```
   JEKLL_ENV=production bundle exec jekyll build
   ```

   (on Windows, you need to run `set JEKLL_ENV=production` first followed by the jekyll incantation.
2. To use a third-party theme that requires only official plugins, and the theme-repo itself is also hosted on GitHub, you can use the `remote_theme` feature (included by default in recent versions of `gem "github-pages"`):

   ```
   # _config.yml

   remote_theme: aron-bordin/neo-hpstr-jekyll-theme
   ```

   Refer: https://github.com/benbalter/jekyll-remote-theme for details on the `jekyll-remote-theme` plugin usage.

Comment: Thanks it worked, however step 2 didn't work for me, whenever I tried to run the command "gem 'jekyll-remote-theme'" I got an unknown command error thrown at me. But all I had to do was to "set HEKLL_ENV=production" and then "bundle exec jekyll build". Commit and push, and then everything was fine. Thanks again!

Comment: I'd like to upvote too, but I just signed up for github so I am not allowed to do so.

Comment: `gem 'jekyll-remote-theme'` is not a command-line command.. its an entry to be made into your `Gemfile` like the plugin's repository has documented..

Answer (score 0):

As you're pushing locally generated code, you need to :

- In ***_config.yml***, set `url: https://sebastian3495.github.io`
- Run a `bundle exec jekyll build`
- Push the resulting code to github.